# get_next_post_link() and get_previous_post_link() return wrong posts

Tags: next-post-link, previous-post-link

I'm using `get_next_post_link()` and `get_previous_post_link()` within the loop but the returned posts are not correct.

`get_next_post_link()` shows the previous post and `get_previous_post_link()` gives the current post. Below the context of these links:

```
$args['name'] = $postname;
$query = new WP_Query($args);

if($query->have_posts())
    {
    while ($query->have_posts())
        {
        $query->the_post();

        $id         = get_the_ID();
        $title          = get_the_title();
        $content        = get_the_content();

        $nextpost       = get_next_post_link('Next: %link');
        $previouspost   = get_previous_post_link('Prev: %link');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved by changing `Site Address (URL)` in `Settings > General` to the path that matches with the posts's path. I was pulling in posts from another location in my website that did not match with the original (default) path of the post.

Comment: This is an interesting issue. Did you know that your rest URL also changes with weird things and just `rest_url` isn't enough?

Answer (score 0):

```
get_next_post_link();
get_previous_post_link();
```

These work on single posts for navigation from one single post to another NOT pagination for archive pages unless you use `get_query_var( 'paged' )`

Answer (score -1):

I think you can not pass proper argument. Please check this link for reference : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_next_posts_link

Comment: You refer to the next archive page post link. The get_next_post_link should be singular to get the adjacent post